# SlideMenu not detecting touches for dismiss menu on iOS 11. Why?

Tags: ios

I'm using the pod [iOS-Slide-Menu](https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu) repo in one of my personal projects.

If I run my project on iOS < 11 everything works as expected: When the side menu (blue view controller), touching outside it, i.e. the green part. Automatically closes it

[image]

But running on a device with iOS 11 the menu does't get closed when tapping outside.

Another curious situation is that this only happen with recently compiled versions (currently using Xcode 9.0), running the App Store version on a iOS11 device also works correctly.

**So my questions are:**

- Why is this happening?
- How can I avoid this to happen without replacing the whole library?

I created a [SAMPLE PROJECT](https://github.com/HeysonDev/iosSlideMenu_ProblemSample) in github to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look at my updated code it's working same like iOS 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SlideNavigationController.m` file go to `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and remove or comment below line

```
 [self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];
```

It is because `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method gets called in `ios 11` initially!

so, from `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, `enableTapGestureToCloseMenu` gets called and it is removing gesture recognizer from right menu!

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Adrime i have downloaded your code and tested in Xcode 9.0
found same issue like you have. outside tapped not closed view.

after seeing library i have found one solution.

In SlideNavigationController.m file,

one method is already created which is `- (void)enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:(BOOL)enable`

in that method, just comment this one line `[self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];`

and your problem is solved.

this line removedGesture of tapping outside.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

I got it what you want, just change your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    // Update shadow size of enabled
    if (self.enableShadow)
        self.view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.view.bounds].CGPath;

    // When menu open we disable user interaction
    // When rotates we want to make sure that userInteraction is enabled again
    //[self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
        self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

    self.topViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if (self.menuNeedsLayout)
    {
        [self updateMenuFrameAndTransformAccordingToOrientation];

        // Handle different horizontal/vertical slideOffset during rotation
        // On iOS below 8 we just close the menu, iOS8 handles rotation better so we support keepiong the menu open
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0") && [self isMenuOpen])
        {
            Menu menu = (self.horizontalLocation > 0) ? MenuLeft : MenuRight;
            [self openMenu:menu withDuration:0 andCompletion:nil];
        }

        self.menuNeedsLayout = NO;
    }
}
```

What I Did : Do comment `//[self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];` code and put below code

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
  self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
self.topViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

**OLD:**

It's Because in `SlideNavigationController.m` file you are calling `[self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];`

Just remove it or make condition for iOS 11 to pass **YES** for all

For EX.

```
if (IOS_VERSION == 11) {
  [self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:YES];
}
else {
  [self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];
}
```

Because when you open your slide menu or click on green area alway call

```
[self enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:NO];
```

So as per method code

```
   - (void)enableTapGestureToCloseMenu:(BOOL)enable
{
    if (enable)
    {
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;

        self.topViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
    }
    else
    {
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
            self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;

        self.topViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapRecognizer];
    }
}
```

It's `removeGestureRecognizer` for view.